# Incorrect path for Pods.debug.xcconfig in Xcode?

Tags: cocoapods, xcode6.1, xcconfig

so I used [Venmo/Synx](https://github.com/venmo/synx) on my Xcode project with CocoaPods, and it completely screwed everything up.

I was able to fix the Manifest.lock and Podfile.lock errors, but now I am getting this error:

> The file “Pods.debug.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/Users/user/GitHub/xxxxxx/Pods/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig)

As you can see, the path is incorrect, as there is no `Pods/Pods` directory (there is one extra pod).

How can I fix this?  I have only added `PODS_ROOT` to the user-defined variable, as that fixed my Podfile and Manifest.lock files.

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

**Edit:**

After adding PODS_ROOT, I get this when running `pod install`.

```
[!] The `Project [Debug]` target overrides the `PODS_ROOT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Comment: Just running `pod install` again may fix this issue.

Comment: @KeithSmiley I've tried that many times, including removing all traces of CocoaPods and then re adding.  I've tried `pod update` too, to no avail.  Just can't nail this issue.

Comment: `Pods` should be excluded from the synx as well: https://github.com/venmo/synx/blob/master/lib/synx/project.rb#L10

Comment: @KeithSmiley Yeah, I saw that too, however, I am using SVProgressHUD, and when I ran `synx` it removes all the images, so I just ran pod install again, which gave me all the errors.  I fixed it by adding PODS_ROOT to get rid of the Podfile.lock and the Manifest.lock error.  Now I'm getting this error :/

Comment: just double checking... are you opening the workspace file? or the .xcodeproj

Comment: @Ben Definitely the workspace file.  I see the xcconfig and everything, the path is just off.

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3341 "These warnings are not build warnings, they are about your SVN repository."

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I had the same problem in Xcode 6.1.1. I did the following to solve it:

1. Set the configuration file setting* "None" for the Pods related target.
2. Close the .xcworkspace.
3. run pod install again
4. now open and build your .xcworkspace

*The configuration file setting is found by selecting the project (not the target) and then the Info tab.

Comment: What do you mean with 1. Set the project setting "None" for the Pods related target.

Comment: For step number 1, this setting is found by selecting the project (not the target) and then the Info tab.

Comment: doesnt work anymore, the settings gets overriden by pod install

Comment: Select Project -> Info tab -> Configurations -> Debug -> Change file setting to "None"

Comment: There was a second config file i could select from, selecting that fixed it

Answer (score 36):

If your path to pods in error is wrong try this:

- use `pod deintegrate`
- delete all pod remains files - `Podfile.lock`, `Pods`, `<Project>.xcworkspace`
- open `<Project>.xcodeproj`
- remove `Pods` project on left side
- try `pod install`

Comment: This plus updating Cocoapods before doing so did the trick for me.  Thanks!  In Terminal project folder - sudo gem update cocoapods

Comment: This worked for me except after performing all these steps I had to do 'Clean Build Folder' and delete 'Derived Data'.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem with `Xcode 11` but I just updated CocoaPods and it worked.

1. Update CocoaPods to latest version with `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. Run `pod install` again

Comment: This is the solution, If you tried to migrate your pods to Swift 5.

Comment: Current in 2019.

Comment: This solution didn't work when I mix it with other solutions. But, when applied it again as a fresh and only solution then it WORKED.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error while trying to build my project for the first time. This is how I resolved it:

- pod deintegrate
- sudo gem install cocoapods-clean
- pod clean

Open the project and delete the “Pods” folder that should be red.

- pod setup
- pod install

Reopen and build the project, I think it's good to go!

Answer (score 8):

I faced this issue when I upgraded/downgraded cocoapods between 1.6.x and 1.5.x.
The following step fixed this error

1, go to project info tab

2, just under Deployment target, there is configurations field. change your  configuration. In my case, there are 2 options

```
/Users/user/GitHub/xxxxxx/Pods/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig

/Users/user/GitHub/xxxxxx/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig
```

3, clean and build again.

Answer (score 3):

1- Remove your `Pods` folder `Podfile.lock` and `xcworkspace` files root in your project.

2- Open `.xcodeproj`

3- Go to Build Settings and under Build Options search `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries`

4- Update its value with `$(inherited)`

5- Close project and `pod install` again

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There has been an update to cocoa pods that is causing this problem.  Please refer to the cocoa pods release notes :

> Change shell script relative paths to use ${PODS_ROOT} instead of ${SRCROOT}/Pods.
>   Whirlwind #7878

This was done in version 1.6.0.beta.1 (2018-08-16)
Release notes are here:  [cocoapods release notes](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Build server was using 1.5.3 and dev machine was using 1.6.1

Answer (score 2):

I got the same situation in `Xcode 10.1`. This is what works for me.

1. Open `<Project>.xcworkspace`
2. Go into your `<project_name>` folder(by default it's blue), delete the `Pods` folder (by default it's yellow)
3. In `Terminal.app`, run `pod install` again
4. Then I'm able to `CMD + R` to run the simulator

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Wei. Mine's Xcode 10.2.1 with CP version 1.5.3. This happened after merging commits from a teammate who's using CP 1.7.

Comment: @Euridice01  In `Terminal.app`, under your project folder

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I fixed in following way

1 - Goto your projected setting by blue icon of your project from left pan
2 - Select your project under the project 
3 - Select Info window
4 - Check IOS deployement target. This target should be same as you set in general settings of your project (Pic 2).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to project directory right click on

project.xcodeproj -> show package contents -> open project.pbxproj

Find

> "Pods/Target Support Files/

and replace with

> "Target Support Files/

This solution will work at any cost!

Answer (score 1):

A few things worth trying:

- As Keith mentioned above, you definitely want to exclude `Pods` from synx.
- You almost certainly do not want to override the `PODS_ROOT` build setting.
- I've seen similar errors to yours in a project with multiple targets. Make sure that your `Podfile` includes a `link_with` setting that specifies all your app targets.
- If you have at least one test target, consider using your `Podfile` to explicitly import all your app pods to both your application and test targets.
- I've not too much experience using a custom `xcconfig` with CocoaPods, but you might first try removing your xcconfig and allowing CocoaPods to generate its own first.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jonathan.  A few things:  I am not using a custom xcconfig, just trying to use the one built.  I am only overriding the PODS_ROOT build setting because it is fixing the Podfile.lock and Manifest.lock missing error, which also started after running synx.  I am only using one target, and tried link_with.

Comment: Okay, but I really don't think that's the underlying issue here. I would be surprised if your custom `PODS_ROOT` isn't causing more problems than it is solving.

Comment: it's possible, but how do I go from there, then?

Answer (score 1):

1. Close project
2. Do *pod deintegrate*
3. Delete - Podfile.lock, Pods,.xcworkspace in project directory
4. Do *sudo gem install cocoapods*
5. Do *pod install*

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the debug.xcconfig file and run pod install again. It solved my issue

Comment: where did you find that file ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted my Podfile, Podfile.lock.
Run `pod init`, then copy all pods to new Podfile, then run `pod install` again and it's worked.
I think it's happened for the differences from folder paths in the old project (for me, I cloned another project from Git repo).

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing `Build system` to `Legacy` in `File` -> `workspace settings` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

For me, this caused after I updated cocoapods. So, I downgraded and the build worked again.

To downgrade, first list of all your versions:

```
sudo gem list cocoapods
```

Then specify the you want to delete (for me was 1.8.4):

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

Then, with 1.5.3 worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me !

I use always Bundler to manage ruby dependencies, then in all my iOS projects i have Gemfile that look like this !

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "cocoapods"
gem "fastlane"
gem "jazzy"

gem 'xcodeproj', :git => 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj.git'
gem 'fastlane-plugin-teams', :git => "https://github.com/mbogh/fastlane-plugin-teams"

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

i just run the following, i advice you using alias for this :

```
## Alias to add in zshrc or bashrc

# bundle install
bdli() {
  bundle install $@;
}

piu() {
  kill $(ps aux | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}');
  pod deintegrate;
  pod repo update;
  pod install;
  pod update;
  open -a Xcode *.xcworkspace;
}
```

then simply run :

```
bdli && piu
```

It will do everything for you :)

PS : To install Bundler go here -> [Bundler](https://bundler.io/)

Answer (score 0):

```
pod deintegrate ("Deintegrate your project from CocoaPods. Removing all traces of CocoaPods from your Xcode project:")
pod install
```

edit the **.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj** file and change the PBXGroup "path = Pods" to "name = Pods"