# Xcode, Pods ProjectName.debug.xcconfig unable to open file. Wrong directory

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

When I build project, I see build error: `ProjectName.debug.xcconfig unable to open file`. I couldn't understand my problem for a long time, but today I take attention, what directory is wrong: full error: `projectName/Pods/Pods...ProjectName.debug.xcconfig unable to open file` Where `Pods` part duplicated, so correct directory must be as `projectName/Pods...ProjectName.debug.xcconfig` How to fix it?

Comment: You may of forgotten to run `pod install` :)

Comment: This absolutely solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129409/2276920

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Xcode 10.1
After trying other suggestions found here #8091 (comment) and at [Incorrect path for Pods.debug.xcconfig in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109476/incorrect-path-for-pods-debug-xcconfig-in-xcode)
I found that Kaspik's suggestion worked:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

edit the .xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file and change the PBXGroup "path = Pods" to "name = Pods"
source https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8091

updated from: pod reintegrate to: pod deintegrate

Comment: I tried above and some more suggestions but didnt work. this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313134/430690

Comment: The problem I had was actually the "path = Pods" in my .pbxproj file, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to change the "paths" to "name". That's the key!

Comment: This solution worked for me. Changed the "paths" to "name" and then do the pod deintegrate, pod install.

Comment: ..and cleaning your build folder never hurts :)

Comment: Reinstall pod worked for me, didn't need to rename "path = Pod"

Comment: The above did work for me although other team members did not see this same error when checked out the same commit. The final solution for me was to wipe my local repo and re-clone.

Comment: The `deintegrate` & `install` worked for me, but first I needed to move to the project directory with `cd ios/App/` then execute the commands.

Comment: Note that you have to actually go into your_project/ios/ folder and then execute these 2 commands there, if you use react-native.

Answer (score 22):

I have encored with this solution...Here is how I solved

```
Close Xcode, 
run on terminal "pod install"
open xcode,
clean build folder and run again
```

Comment: If you are wondering how to navigate to the clean build folder on Xcode >> Products >> clean build folder

Answer (score 5):

Remove the duplicates from the Pods folder ƒrom xcode project here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Deleting extra files in `target->Linked Frameworks and Libraries` solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Run `pod repo update` first and then you should be able to install pods with `yarn install:pods` if you're using yarn.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

1. Delete .xcworkspace file
2. Go to project build phases - delete **Check Pods Manifest.lock** and **Embed Pods Framework** section
3. Remove Pods folder from the left project navigator
4. Remove Pods folder from the project directory
5. Delete everything related to pods except Podfile
6. Do **Pod install**

This should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clean build folder. Then use the code following:

```
pod reintegrate 
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

first, try to update cocopods

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

and after that clean cocopods cache

`pod cache clean --all`

now install posd:

`pod install`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manage by reopening Xcode, in my case i had already run pod install with the ide open (Xcode 12.0).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in CI. Simply running `xcodebuild clean` fixed it for me.
In Xcode that'd be equivalent to `cmd + shift + k`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue, I checked my npm modules was corrupted so I deleted npm modules

And npm install ==> cd iOS ==> pod install.

And the code works smoothly!
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Better solution for further this kind of issues
$ cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master