# CocoaPods debug.xcconfig: unable to open file in target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have my code from my other machine, which is working without `pod install`, but after pod install it gives me following error

> error: /Users/UserName/Documents/MyApp/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-MyApp.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "MyApp" in project "MyApp") (in target 'MyApp')

Tried `pod deintegrate` and `pod init` again given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558984/xcode-pods-projectname-debug-xcconfig-unable-to-open-file-wrong-directory), deleted `Podfile.lock` and Pod folder.

pod --version  1.7.4

Xcode - 10.2

Comment: Something wrong with your project MyApp.xcodeproj . Please check it and update it.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8091#issuecomment-421538684) helped:

> 1. “pod deintegrate”
> 2. “sudo gem install cocoapods-clean”
> 3. “pod clean”
> 4. Open the project and delete the “Pods” folder that should be red
> 5. “pod setup”
> 6. “pod install”