# Can't find *.xcconfig in cmake generated project after pod install

Tags: xcode, cmake, cocoapods

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558984/xcode-pods-projectname-debug-xcconfig-unable-to-open-file-wrong-directory), [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8091) and [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8091#issuecomment-421537449), but without any luck.
My problem was as title shown, the project was generated by CMake, here are the CMakeLists.txt, main.m and Podfile

```
#CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(target_name test_pods)
project(${target_name})

add_executable(${target_name} main.m)
```

```
//main.m
#import "glfw3.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
     if(!glfwInit())
         return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

```
#Podfile
platform :osx, '10.14'

target 'test_pods' do
  # Pods for test_pods
  pod 'CCGlfw'
end
```

**step by step**
My directory structure is

```
test
│ CMakeLists.txt
| main.m
└───build
| | strip_xcode.py
| | Podfile
| | Pods
| | test_pods.xcodeproj
| | test_pods.xcworkspace 
| | ...
```

1. Generate Xcode project by `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -GXcode`.
2. Then `pod init` and you will find that there is an error message about `Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes...`, this [scrpt](https://gist.github.com/johnb003/59842c752cbbbdcde00e2ca8ca33d4cb) will fix this error by `python3 strip_xcode.py -p test_pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`.
3. `pod install` to install the dependencies, i.e. glfw3
4. you can ignore the message like `... target overrides the GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS ...`(we not focus on this), open **test_pods.xcworkspace**, in the left panel, go to **test_pods -> Pods**, click **Pods-test_pods.debug.xcconfig**, you will find that you can't open it. The full path will be shown in the right panel `path_to/test/Target Support Files/Pods-test_pods/Pods-test_pods.debug.xcconfig`, while the ture path is `path_to/test/build/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-test_pods/Pods-test_pods.debug.xcconfig`. The folder **build/Pods** can't be recognized.

I think maybe there is something wrong with `${SRCROOT}` or `${PODS_ROOT}`? I google a lot but still can't fix my issue, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in cocoapods which leads to incorrect install_dir handling in relative build environments. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6268#issuecomment-443689964

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.