# How to manually download GitHub iOS code and have it work in XCode 11.7?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, github

**INTRO**

Greetings!

I have recently been granted access to a proprietary (that is, private) GitHub repository for iOS development.  I'm on a Mac (OS 10.15.6 Catalina, the latest MacOS as of this writing) with the latest non-beta XCode version installed today (11.7) as well as the latest iOS emulator as of this writing (iOS 13.7).  I am new at using Macs, at XCode, and working with this project, and the author of this GitHub code hasn't been available to help me work with his code.  (I am well familiar with downloading files from GitHub and the Internet in general.)

I know this GitHub repo has XCode inside because there's an XCode file, Pods.xcodeproj.  There are also many other files, including .xcconfig files.

It may be a hardware problem.  This Mac's technical specs were minimalistic:  It has less than 4 gig of physical RAM and a recently-obtained hard disk space upgrade to put it around 70 gig of total space, or enough to work with Android Studio and XCode.  (A sample project failed to run in the simulator due to having too little RAM.)

Thus, what's wrong and how should it be fixed?

Thankee!

**ERROR MESSAGE**

Build target hornet of project hornet with configuration Release
error: /Users/Liam/Desktop/HORNET/9-1-20/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-hornet/Pods-hornet.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "hornet" in project "hornet") (in target 'hornet' from project 'hornet')

error: /Users/Liam/Desktop/HORNET/9-1-20/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-hornet/Pods-hornet.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "hornet" in project "hornet") (in target 'hornet' from project 'hornet')

error: /Users/Liam/Desktop/HORNET/9-1-20/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-hornet/Pods-hornet.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "hornet" in project "hornet") (in target 'hornet' from project 'hornet')

error: /Users/Liam/Desktop/HORNET/9-1-20/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-hornet/Pods-hornet.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "hornet" in project "hornet") (in target 'hornet' from project 'hornet')

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: For error messages you're getting, try this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558984/xcode-pods-projectname-debug-xcconfig-unable-to-open-file-wrong-directory

Comment: I wasn't sure when in the process of discussion I should accept an answer.  So far, even after following your instructions, I got the same errors when building/running this project.  (I confirmed I opened the .xcworkspace.).  Thus, I didn't feel comfortable yet calling this question answered.  (I needed today to download, install, and check various things.)

I appreciate your aid so far,  Thankee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of the `Pods` path suggests the project is using CocoaPods. If so,

- If you haven’t already, install [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/).
- Once that’s installed on your computer, go to the project root folder in Terminal and run `pod install` to download the pods.
- In Xcode, open the `.xcworkspace`, not the `.xcodeproj`.

But 4gb of RAM may simply be too modest to use Xcode at all. If you can’t create and run a simple test project in Xcode, you certainly won’t be able to open a bigger project. My recollection was a 8gb minimum, but even that will struggle. 16gb is pretty decent and if you can afford more, so much the better.

Comment: Thankee!

What sort of Mac processor do you recommend for working with XCode?

Comment: I bet if you Google “Mac configuration Xcode” you’ll see plenty of suggestions, but my experience is that CPU is less important than first making sure you’ve enough RAM (I’d shoot for 8gb at _absolute_ minimum; 16gb or more if you can swing it) and a SSD drive. CPU is less critical, IMHO. I’d bump ram up to 16gb or more before worrying about high end CPUs. If you’re trying to save money, go mid-range on the Mac and bump RAM up.