React native app getting error when I try to build IOS app using MacOS 14 and xCode 15

/Users/mac/Projects/mobile/texmeta-mobile/ios/TexMeta.xcodeproj:1:1 Unable to open base configuration reference file '/Users/mac/Projects/mobile/texmeta-mobile/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TexMeta/Pods-TexMeta.debug.xcconfig'.
I tried to install pod and build app

Which file you have opened .xcodeproject or .xcworkspce, if you have installed pod then you need to open .xcworkspace file

open .xcworkspce but I tried from vsCode

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/27039447/833395

Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680211/833395, deintegrate pods and install pods. And update the .pbxProject file
